# How do I connect my laptop (without a phone plug) to a phone line?

Tags: laptop, phone

I want to connect my landline phone to my laptop so that I can get the caller ID on my laptop. The problem is that my laptop (HP Envy 14) does not have a telephone plug.

How should I go about doing this?

(FWIW I have an ADSL internet connection through my phone)

Comment: No way. You need to have a phone modem installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add a `USB modem` or a `Card Slot modem`.
Card slots have changed over time.

- PCMCIA
- Cardbus
- Express Card